# Utilizar dart:io y dart:html en el mismo archivo

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo un formulario que recibe un archivo, por lo cual recibe un `File`.
Para mobile uso la librería  *dart:io* y para web *dart:html*. El formulario funciona bien en las 2 plataformas, pero cuando compilo en mobile da error por tener *dart:html* y en web lo contrario.

¿Cómo puedo tener una condicional para que use cierta librería según la plataforma?

Answer (score 1):

Hasta donde tengo entendido no es posible ya que `dart:html` es una biblioteca enfocada del lado del cliente y `dart:io` esta enfocada para el lado del servidor. Una forma para que puedas usar ambas sería creando dos clases y validar en que plataforma estás actualmente y dependiendo de esto presentar la vista con el formulario y el paquete especificado:

```
if(kIsWeb){
  //muestras la pantalla de formulario con la biblioteca dart:html
  showFormWeb();
} else{
  //muestras la pantalla de formulario con la biblioteca dart:io
  showFormMobile();
}
```

`kIsWeb` te permite validar si tu aplicación está corriendo en un navegador web.